# Migrating an old question to HSM or math, or not

Tags: discussion, scope, moderation, unanswered-questions

Ten month ago, I asked [What are references explaining Hugo Steinhaus early “data science” work?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/8587/12527). It remains unanswered.

It seemed to me it was  legitimate on SE.DataScience at this time. Although mathematician, Steinhaus worked on a lot of applied topics, devised early data science tools, and did "invent" k-means. Plus:

- data science is a novel field, probably not yet identified as a science *per se* by others
- such questions appear on SE.Stats.SE or SE.Math.

Now, @aventurin suggested the question would fit better in  [History of science and mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). However, according to [Meta: what is migration and how does it work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work):

> Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated; this
>   rule applies also to moderators. Developers are able to bypass this
>   restriction, but they only do so in very, very rare cases.

Plus, I do not have the reputation to do it directly. What are your suggestions?

- keep it here,
- having it migrated anyway,
- advertise to attract [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) folks?
- else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think that question could fit on either StackExchange. Although this SE tends to be more about algorithms and tools instead of history, the topic seems "data science"-related. I do think it fits somewhat better on HSM, but I wouldn't close it here. Yes I can't migrate it.

You can re-ask on HSM, although if you do it'd be nice to close it here I guess. It's not getting answered here anyway.